# Problem in navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a problem I want to control the backBarButtonItem when I click on it Action backAction "works
**my problem is that SetAction does not work, I hope there is a solution for the controller backBarButtonItem**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTarget:self];
    [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(backAction)];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)backAction {
    if ((isSaveCarte==NO)&&(isNewCarte)) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Voulez vous Enregistrer la Carte" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save",nil]; 

        [alertView show]; 
        [alertView release];                
    }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below, Could be useful for you

[How to trap the back button event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557290/how-to-trap-the-back-button-event/1557930#1557930)

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=637266

[How to create backBarButtomItem with custom view for a UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526520/how-to-create-backbarbuttomitem-with-custom-view-for-a-uinavigationcontroller)

[Assignig a action to backBarButtonItem](https://discussions.apple.com/message/8217960?messageID=8217960)

Answer (score 0):

back bar button item is meant for navigating back...

why don't you use the leftBarButtonItem instead of backBarButtonItem..
the only difference would be it wont be a left pointed button.. but you are not navigating back anyways right?

Comment: I used the left button but it is not good. there is no solution for backButton

Comment: what do you mean theres no solution?? do you want to navigate back with the asme button as well??

Comment: I found a solution, I have a boyfriend (graphic designer) and I just create a button as backButton:)