# Find out if user pressed the back button in uinavigationcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When a view loads, i want to see if it's because the user pressed the back button. How can i check this?

Comment: Do you want to to know whether it was a user initiated popping or popping in general?

Comment: It might be good to elaborate on your overall goal. There might be an easier way to do what you're trying to do. If you need to know whether some value was changed or set in the second view, for instance, you should simply check that value.

Comment: Popping is what i want to be told about.

Answer (score -11, accepted):

The only way to do this so you know for sure that it was the back button is to create a custom button.  If you don't know how to do that, check out this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526520/how-to-create-backbarbuttomitem-with-custom-view-for-a-uinavigationcontroller).  It won't look exactly like the normal back button, but close.  If you need more help, post a comment

Comment: Check andrews other answer, and if the poster reads this perhaps accept that as the correct answer

Comment: @user461864, you mean the other Andrew, not Andrew's other answer--they're different Andrews. But you are right, the other answer is far superior; the present one is a lot of extra work by comparison.

Comment: Damn you are right,.. I thought it was weird that he answered twice but that explains

Comment: This answer is incorrect and should be removed by the poster.

Answer (score 110):

The best solution I've found to detect a UINavigationController's back button press (pre-iOS 5.0) is by verifying that the current view controller is not present in the in the navigation controller's view controller stack.

It is possibly safer to check this condition in `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` as logically, by the time that method is called it would be extremely likely that the view controller was removed from the stack.

Pre-iOS 5.0:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (![[self.navigationController viewControllers] containsObject:self]) {
        // We were removed from the navigation controller's view controller stack
        // thus, we can infer that the back button was pressed
    }
}
```

iOS 5.0+ you can use [-didMoveToParentViewController:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW78)

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    // parent is nil if this view controller was removed
}
```

Comment: This works great! But you mentioned pre-iOS 5.0.. Is there an iOS 5 specific method that can be used to catch the back button callback?

Comment: This gets also gets called when the VC is pushed (at least on iOS 6).

Comment: Hey, viewDidDisappear did not get called in iOS 4.3 for me. While both methods are called for me in iOS 5. Any thoughts?

Comment: didMoveToParentViewController; is not a good solution, it will also be call when this view is appear.

Comment: You need to check if the parent is nil in order to determine if the view was added or removed.

Answer (score 81):

in your viewWillDisappear method check

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if ([self isMovingFromParentViewController]) {
      //specific stuff for being popped off stack
    }
}
```

This is only for post iOS 5

Comment: missing parenthesis in the if statement, but otherwise very helpful answer. thanks!

Comment: As an alternative to this, inspired by Andrew's answer, you can do something before the move by overriding
`willMoveToParentViewController:` instead of `didMoveToParentViewController:`.

Comment: Way better method than programming your custom button. Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't mean exactly if user presses back button. There are tons of other cases when it's triggered

Answer (score 7):

UINavigationController has a `delegate` property that issues delegate callbacks.  Please see [the iOS reference here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UINavigationControllerDelegate).

The delegate doesn't have a "back button pressed" callback, but instead it tells you when something is going to appear on the navigation stack.  When you press back, you are "popping" the top view controller off the stack, so it will tell you that the view is about to appear.  I think this is the callback you'd be looking for.

You could have some simple logic to check if it's the view controller that's "interested", and then you could send a notification, et al.

Comment: There is no delegate that shows when a uinavigationcontroller has popped off the stack

Comment: I said that UINavigationController has a delegate.  If UINavigationController is managing your view hierarchy, it indeed will callback to the delegate, if set.

Comment: I am trying to do this.  When backing up, unfortunately, it calls the "new" view controller [the one being backed up to] -viewWillAppear before the delegate method -navigationController:willShowViewContoller:animated: is called for that same viewController...

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, mix of two most upvoted answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9799305/1226304), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13370744/1226304)) in Swift:

```
override func willMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMoveToParentViewController(parent)
    if parent == nil {
        // view controller is popping
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `will`, use `did` since there's screen edge pop gesture.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly different scenario, but I thought the solution might help others out.

In my situation, I had a UINavigationController within a UIPopoverController.  I needed to detect whether the user clicked the back button, or clicked outside of the popover.  To do this I checked the visibleViewController property in viewWillDisappear.  If the view controller is still the visibleViewController when closing, then the popover is being closed by another means.  If the view controller is not the visibleViewController when closing, then the back button was pressed.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (self.navigationController.visibleViewController != self) {
        <Do something since we're closing using something else>
    } else {
        <Do something since we're closing because of the back button>
    }
}
```

I tried using zach's solution, but isMovingFromParentViewController returns true for both cases.

I verified this works in iOS 5+

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom back bar button and set the target,

Step 1: Add these methods to your class

```
- (void)backButtonClicked :(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)addBackBarButton{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 35);
    [button setTitle:@"back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
}
```

Step 2: Call **[self addBackBarButton];** in viewDiDLoad method

You will get the action in **backButtonClicked** method. You can play around with it the way you want.

Cheers!