# iOS master detail application back button

Tags: ios, button, back, master-detail

How can I imitate back button (navigation bar) using code?

I want return from detail view to master view with code.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557290/how-to-trap-the-back-button-event

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910994/view-controllers-how-to-switch-between-views-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

That will "pop" (opposite of push) the current view controller off the navigation stack. Exactly what the back button does.

Comment: No worries. If I helped you feel free to press the up button on the left next to my answer and click the tick to set as the answer to your question.