# What method is called after tap back button in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have 2 View Controllers with Navigation Controller.
When I Use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in the second one - the first one opens but the methods in viewDidLoad don't called. What are the methods called in the first one controller in this situation?

Comment: The view is already loaded, they don't unload until they get popped off. Don't use ARC if you're new, just my recommendation.

Comment: See Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557290/how-to-trap-the-back-button-event

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The navigation controller sends `viewWillAppear:` to a view controller before putting its view on the screen, and `viewDidAppear:` after.

Inside `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:`, the view controller can check `self.isMovingToParentViewController`.  If `isMovingToParentViewController` is `YES`, the view controller is being added to the navigation controller in the first place (presumably because it's the navigation controller's root view controller, or because it is being pushed).  If `isMovingToParentViewController` is `NO`, the view controller is already in the navigation controller's stack, and another view controller is being popped to reveal it.

Read [“Handling View-Related Notifications” in the `UIViewController` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#1652793).

Answer (score 1):

In that case `viewWillAppear` method will be called.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}
```

Comment: Thank u! Now I see how to make this!

Comment: Don't forget to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` ! :)