# Unwind segue from navigation back button in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I have a settings screen, in that I have a table cell. By clicking on that I take to another screen where user can choose an option and I want it back in the previous view controller when back button is pressed.

[image: image first view controller][image: image second view controller]

I can put a custom bar button item, but I want to return to the parent view controller using the back button in the navigation bar rather than with a custom button on the view.

I don't seem to be able to override the navigation back button to point it down to my unwind segue action and since the back button doesn't appear on the storyboard, I cant drag the green Exit button to it

Is it possible to unwind a push segue with the back button?

Comment: I achieved what I was trying to do, i.e., pass data back up in a navigation controller stack using delegate method: http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/05/using-delegates-and-segues-part-2-the-pizza-demo-app/

Comment: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/

Answer (score 5):

Here's my solution, based on Objective-C code from Blankarsch to this StackOverflow question: [How to trap the back button event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557290/how-to-trap-the-back-button-event)

Put this code inside the View Controller you want to trap the Back button call from:

```
override func didMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    if (!(parent?.isEqual(self.parentViewController) ?? false)) {
        println("Back Button Pressed!")
    }
}
```

Inside of the if block, handle whatever you need to pass back. You'll also need to have a reference back to calling view controller as at this point most likely both parent and self.parentViewController are nil, so you can't navigate the View Controller tree.

Also, you might be able to get away with simply checking parent for nil as I haven't found a case where pressing the back button didn't result in parent being nil. So something like this is a bit more concise:

```
override func didMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    if (parent == nil) {
        println("Back Button Pressed!")
    }
}
```

But I can't guarantee that will work every time.

Comment: Brilliant! I wanted to have the control before switching to it and gladly I went for: override func willMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) which works equally good, and well before the view transitions. Thanks again for this.

Comment: you forgot `super.didMove(...)`

Comment: Here too, @Cœur ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do the following in the view controller that **has** the back button

**Swift 3**

```
override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    if !(parent?.isEqual(self.parent) ?? false) {
        print("Parent view loaded")
    }
    super.didMove(toParentViewController: parent)
}
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree if the code didn't work but then again, I wouldn't have posted the answer.

Comment: I think, it should go to the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and it seems that you cannot catch the standard back button's action so the solution will be to use a custom button and bind it to a segue which leads back to the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of delegation as you did or use a custom back button and an unwind segue.

Better even, you could handle passing data between your view controllers using a mediator:

http://cocoapatterns.com/passing-data-between-view-controllers/