# Setting custom back button to look like default back button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to make a custom back button but also want to retain the default look of the back button. I simply want the look of the default back arrow (<) without any text. The code I am using is

```
    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goBack")
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

But this makes the back button looks all wrong. I can't find anywhere how/what to change the button to look like the default look. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can check the answers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717315/perform-segue-on-press-on-back-button/31717425#31717425 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807997/back-button-image-what-is-it-called-in-swift/31808361#31808361

Comment: no need of coding , r u used the storyboard or xib

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one View controller on the Stack default back arrow will come automatically by using simple below code:-

```
self.navigationController?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(//your code);
```

If you do not have more than one View controller on the Stack then you can do the tweak by putting the back button image like this:-

```
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: "BackButtonimage", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: "goBack")
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the "goBack" function (see original post) is never called by the system.