# swift4: back button in SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

i'm using `swift4`, this is my design structure [image: the structure]
first view controller is `SWRevealViewController` has `sw_front` segue to `UITabBarViewController`, and `sw_rear` to `UITableViewController`

i have back button and menu button in every view controller, I want to use the default action of back button in each view controller baut i didn't know how, is there any way that solve this problem

Comment: you need to create `BaseViewController` in that you need to write back button and menu button code and inherit to every controller.

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint   back button with which segue I have four different segue types tabs, reveal view controller push controller, reveal view controller set controller, and push segue ??

Answer (score 0):

```
    class SuperViewController: UIViewController {
func goBackNavigationBarItem(){
        //Left Button - Navigation bar
        let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: imgName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(SuperViewController.btnBackClicked(_:)))

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
    }

func btnBackClicked(_ sender:UIButton!){
    // whatever action You want on back button 
}
}
```

make your viewController child of SuperViewController and 
Call this function **goBackNavigationBarItem()**  in **viewDidLoad()** of every view controller Like this..

```
class AnyVC: SuperViewController{

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        goBackNavigationBarItem()
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: thank you, but my problem is the action of back button for example in bottom view controller what would the back button action be as i navigated to it with segue reveal view controller push controller

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358482/unwind-segue-from-navigation-back-button-in-swift check this..